# Svelte - store auto subscription - value does not get updated

Tags: svelte

I have 3 files concerned with this issue.  One is a component file, one is a JS library file  and the other is the store file.

Store file:

```
import { writable } from "svelte/store";

export const appStore = writable({
    currentPage : '',
});
```

Library file:

```
import { appStore } from "../stores/appStore";

let store;

appStore.subscribe(data => {
    store = data;
});

export async function post() {
    console.log(store);
}
```

and finally, component file:

```
import { test } from '$lib/req_utils';
import { appStore } from "../../stores/AppStore";

appStore.update(store => {
    store.currentPage = 'login';
    return store;
});

function handleLogin() {
    test();
}
```

Basically, when the component file is loaded, the currentPage in the store is set to 'login' and when the handleLogin event is trigerred. the test function is called in my library JS and the library JS will output the value of appStore.currentPage - which correctly will be 'login'.

However, when I attempt to use autosubscribe in the component file as follows:

```
import { test } from '$lib/req_utils';
import { appStore } from "../../stores/AppStore";

$appStore.currentPage = 'login';

function handleLogin() {
    test();
}
```

the store does not seem to get updated (when checking the value in test() in the library JS)

Based on the docs and tutorials I have watched the above should be working?

Answer (score 0):

It looked that since Svelte reactivity is based on assignment, assigning a value to a property of an object isn't triggering the reactivity. However, [I've set up a demo of your case in the Svelte REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/6b70323ed85743e9a952d63567aedbd9?version=3.44.3) and it seems to be working fine.

Maybe it's something to do with the test functions? I have to say it would seem strange to me since you claim that the `update` method does work.

Some other ideas of what's causing the problem that come to me are that somewhere the `currentPage` property is being reseted. Or maybe the way the test function is written, the `store` variable binds on initialization. Either way, I believe that both using `update` and `$` should be identical.

[This GitHub issue](https://github.com/sveltejs/svelte/issues/4285) could have relevant information, but I didn't find anything.